# Style button doesn't work inside the listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I create a usercontorl for listbox. User will go to different page by selecting the textbox inside the buttons. I must use the textbox because the contest need to wrap.  I want to change the background color during the clicking. However, the button sytle doesn't work. Would someone can show me the example or link or hint to solve my problem.

The following is my style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="btnCall" TargetType="Button" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.1" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:00.1" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <!--<Border Name="NormalBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Fuchsia" BorderThickness="1" />-->
                        <Border x:Name="NormalBackground" BorderThickness="0" />
                        <Border x:Name="HoverBackground"  Opacity="0" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="3" Background="Gray" />
                        <Border x:Name="PressedBackground" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="LightSteelBlue" />

                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

I put the listbox in the grid as belows:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}" Background="#00E23162">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstCall" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360"     >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                          

                        <Button  Width="460" Height="70" Style="{StaticResource btnCall}"  ClickMode="Press" Click="Detail_Click" >
                            <Button.Content >

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="65" Width="400">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Type}" Width="35" Height="35"/>

                                    <TextBlock  Width="240" Height="65" Text="{Binding summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                             Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"   />


                                    <Button Width="135" Height="65" ClickMode="Press" Click="Action_Click" Style="{StaticResource btnCall}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding isVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                                        <Button.Content>                                               
                                            <TextBlock Width="200" Height="65" Text="{Binding ActionCaption}" 
                                                       Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle_20}"     />
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>


                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Why you created a `Style` in a `UserControl` while no additional xaml there? And this `UserControl` is not used in code you shown...

Comment: why do you have a button within a button?

Comment: The user control is put on the other page.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I shouldn't have a button within a button. I modifed the xaml and there is only a button, textblock and image in the stackPanel which is inside the DataTemplate. I found out the sytle is only applied on Visusal State in Normal statues. The pressed status doesn't fired. Would someone show me to solve this problem. Thanks.